# JSONP with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, json, prototypejs, jsonp

I'm trying to retrieve JSON data from a remote site with Rails/Prototype.

I've found that there's [a branch of Prototype](http://github.com/dandean/Ajax.JSONRequest) that has an `Ajax.JSONRequest()` function. I can't get this to work.

jQuery has a `$.getJSON()` function, but I'm using some Prototype functions and I'd rather not switch to jQuery or use no conflict mode.

What am I missing? It seems like this would be easily done with Rails or Prototype.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You mention you want to get json with Rails, but want to use JavaScript? Who do you want making the request - the server or the client?

Comment: I'm asking if there is a Rails helper for JSONP. Client-side or server-side. Edited original post for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to use Rails helpers to make the client request JSON?  It's easy with [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/learn/json)

```
new Ajax.Request('/some_url', {
  method: 'get',
  onSuccess: function(transport) {
    var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
  }
});
```

You just need to make sure that /some_url responds with JSON to an XHTTPRequest (preferably using respond_to?, but you can also check request.xhr?), using Rails' Object#to_json method.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the JSONP rack middlware that's available in rack-contrib.  This gives you the ability to just append &callback=method to your query string and have the response from rails wrapped in your callback method.

Just add this to your application.rb:

```
require "rack/contrib/jsonp"

class Application < Rails::Application
  config.middleware.use Rack::JSONP
end
```

Comment: There is a gem for this now, rack-jsonp that works the same way; in a Rails 3.x application you won't need the `require` and you'd just have to add `gem 'rack-jsonp'` to your Gemfile and `bundle install`.

Answer (score 1):

nothing built into rails specifically for jsonp, but there's a couple things that you could do if you wanted your rails app to play nice with jsonp.

- create a jsonp mime-type in config/initializers/mime_types.rb
- extend object with a to_jsonp method that will wrap calls to json in your passed callback. something like:

def to_jsonp(callback, options={})
  "#{callback}(#{self.to_json(options)})"
end

- follow this guys article.

http://blogs.sitepoint.com/2006/10/05/json-p-output-with-rails/